# How to remove black fields from svg

Tags: html, css, image, animation, svg

I have the following svg code that I want to animate but I end up with black fields or "sahdows" beneath my lines. I can't seem to be able to get rid of them, anyone have a clue as to why?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 750" style="background-color: #E6E6E0; xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#30D5C8">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#30D5C8; #f2c80f; #30D5C8" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f2c80f">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#f2c80f; #30D5C8; #f2c80f" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
<path d="m959 373c-48.5-115.5-97.5-231-153-231-111 0-195 462-306 462s-195-462-306-462c-55.5 0-104.5 115.5-153 231" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="16">
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="1000" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
</svg>
```

I've tried changing every colour code from the code. I expected to remove the color black and to have no "shadow" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the dark color below the first and third section and above the second, then you need to specifically apply a fill="none" to your path:

```
 <path d="m959 373c-48.5-115.5-97.5-231-153-231-111 0-195 462-306 462s-195-462-306-462c-55.5 0-104.5 115.5-153 231" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="16" fill="none">
```

Without this, the renderer assumes you want the default fill color for your shape.